# how to compare the charaters in excel

Tags: excel

```
sheet 1              sheet 2             sheet 3                    sheet 4
  a                     a                   a                          a
  b                     b                   b                          b
  c                     c                   c                          c
  a                     a                   b                          a
  b                     b                   a                          b
  c                     c                   a                          c
  a                     b                   c                          b
```

My question is if all the three sheets contains the same letter then the `sheet 4` should contain the same letter.

if `sheet 1` and `sheet 2` contains `a` and `sheet 3` contains `b` then the result should be `a` in `sheet 4`.

if all the sheets has different letters then the result in `sheet 4` should be `b`.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? And what do you mean by the result should be `b` if all are different? If should give the value from `sheet 2` when all are different?

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Excel **EXACT** function compares two strings and returns TRUE if both values are the same. Otherwise, it will return FALSE.

**EXCEL EXACT SYNTAX**

```
EXACT( text1, text2 )
```

---

```
=EXACT(A1, A2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a if-then-else statement in Excel, it looks like =IF(A=B,True,False); And you can nest one in another.

In sheet 4 (for the example cell A1) =IF(Sheet1!A1="a",IF(Sheet2!A1="a",IF(Sheet3!A1="a","a", "b"),"b"),"b")

This check is sheet1 is A, yes? check sheet 2 etc, else give B.

More about IF in excel: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if.php